# Switch to Frame by STYLE?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I am trying to switch to a frame that allows me to type some words.

HTML:

```
 <iframe style="height: 170px; width: 407px;">
   #document
    <html webdriver="true">
       <head></head>
      <body>
           <br _editor_node="TRUE"</br>

  </body>
  </html>
  </iframe>
```

The 1st code I tried:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('br[_moz_editor_bogus_node="TRUE"]').send_keys('hi')
```

2nd Code I tried:

```
for handle in driver.window_handles:
        driver.switch_to.window(handle)

driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('br[_moz_editor_bogus_node="TRUE"]')
```

My error:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css 
>   selector","selector":"br[_moz_editor_bogus_node=\"TRUE\"]"}
>   Stacktrace:

Is there a way to switch to the frame by the style?

## this doesnt work

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[style="height:.177px;.width.407px;"]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The most logical approach, given what you provided, would be to get the `iframe` element having the desired element inside it:

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[br[@_moz_editor_bogus_node="TRUE"]]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

Comment: did you mean css_selector or xpath? what is css_xpath?

Comment: @royalblue oops :) I guess I should not do 10 things at the same time, fixed.